# How to sync a bug fix across all branches?

Tags: git

Assume a scenario where I have a repo and there are 3 branches, master - where all the deployment code lives, and two feature branches A and B which are being used by different developers and have commits that can't be discarded. Suppose there is a bug that is affecting the work on branch A and branch B. What will be the ideal way to complete this task?
What I've been doing is creating a 3rd branch 'C', implementing the fixes, and then merging it with the master, pushing it to the origin, pulling the changes on the devs' machine, and merging the branches A and B with the master. But it seems it isn't the ideal way to do it. It somehow feels really jank. Is there a better way to do it?

Also, if there are some pro tips for newbies like me, please shower us with your wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not abhor merges, the ideal procedure is:

- You create a new branch `C` that forks from `master` before `A` and `B` were forked off. Ideally, that is the commit that introduced the bug that you are fixing.
- You merge `C` into `master`, `A`, and `B`.

You should not merge `C` into `master` and then the resulting `master` into `A` and `B` because you get all of `master`'s commits into `A` and `B`, and that is unnecessary complexity that you do not want at this point.

Comment: Thanks. I have another question. There are times when we have to add common dependencies to branches A and B because it is required by a change in requirements of a feature or different timelines of the introduction of the feature. Is it wise to introduce that dependency in both the branches and merging them later?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "introduce that dependency in both the branches". If it means what I think it means, then I would use the same strategy as for the bug fix.

Comment: Consider a scenario where a developer is working on a feature and installed the required dep, at a later time another feature was planned which required the same dep. Now, dev1 has the dep in his commits already while dev2 needs to add it on the new branch. Adding the dep to master doesn't make much sense because it has production code in it. How should I go on about it?

Comment: Like in the answer (`C` is the dependency), only do not merge `C` to master as a separate step. `C` enters `master` "implicitly" when the first of the two topics is merged.

Comment: Alright, seems simple enough. Are there any other tips that I should follow to make the management seemless?

Comment: Don't rewrite history, in particular not when there are merges. I.e., use `git rebase` only while you are in a hot development sprint or as long as your history is unpublished *and linear*.

Comment: That is helpful and makes perfect sense. Thanks :)